# uglified files are not rewritten in html file using gulp-usemin

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, gulp, grunt-usemin

I am facing a problem with `gulp-usemin` plugin. when `usemin` task is running it is concating and uglifying `css` and `js` files, but the uglified js files are not rewritten in html file though it is generated. I am sharing my gulpfile.js and index.html code .

**`index.html`** *before conversion*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- build:css build/css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blue.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/green.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/orange.css">
        <!-- endbuild -->
        <!-- build:js build/js1 -->
        <script src="js/add.js"></script>
        <script src="js/sub.js"></script>
        <script src="js/mul.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
    </head>
    <body>

        <p class="blue" id="sum"></p>
        <p class="green" id="diff"></p>
        <p class="orange" id="mul"></p>
        <img src="images/1.jpg" width="304" height="228">
        <img src="images/2.jpg" width="304" height="228">

        <script>
        document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML=add(4,4);
        document.getElementById('diff').innerHTML=sub(4,4);
        document.getElementById('mul').innerHTML=mul(4,4);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var usemin = require('gulp-usemin');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var minifyHtml = require('gulp-minify-html');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rev = require('gulp-rev'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify');

gulp.task('usemin', function() {
  gulp.src('./*.html')
    .pipe(usemin({
      css: [minifyCss(), 'concat'],
      html: [minifyHtml({empty: true})],
      js: [uglify()]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

**`index.html`** *after conversion*

```
//you can see that build/css is generated but build/js is not generated
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/css"/>

    </head>
    <body>

    <p class="blue" id="sum"></p>
    <p class="green" id="diff"></p>
    <p class="orange" id="mul"></p>
    <img src="images/1.jpg" width="304" height="228">
    <img src="images/2.jpg" width="304" height="228">

    <script>
    document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML=add(4,4);
    document.getElementById('diff').innerHTML=sub(4,4);
    document.getElementById('mul').innerHTML=mul(4,4);

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Help me in fixing this issue. Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are missing the `rev` in your `js` `usemin` call, change your `task` to:

```
gulp.task('usemin', function() {

  gulp.src('./*.html')
    .pipe(usemin({
      css: [minifyCss(), 'concat'],
      html: [minifyHtml({empty: true})],
      js: [uglify(), rev()]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));

  });
```

Also, the last parameter of the `blocks` in `gulp-usemin` represent the path of a `file`. You  should precise the extension to not confuse with a directory

```
<!-- build:css build/style.css -->

<!-- build:js build/js1.js -->
```

For clarity, you should also put a line break between the two different blocks.