# gulp-usemin not outputting js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-uglify, gulp-usemin

I am trying to use `gulp-usemin` to bundle my `CSS` and `javascript` files for production. `gulp-usemin` is working fine on my `CSS` files, but is not outputting anything in relation to my `javascript` files. Can somebody point out to me what I'm doing wrong?

I'm experiencing a problem similar to [uglified files are not rewritten in html file using gulp-usemin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951637/uglified-files-are-not-rewritten-in-html-file-using-gulp-usemin), but the proposed solution isn't working.

For reference, my `node` version is `v0.12.1` and my `gulp` versions are as follows:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "gulp": "^3.9.1",
  "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
  "gulp-rev": "^7.1.2",
  "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
  "gulp-usemin": "^0.3.24"
}
```

`index.html`

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!-- build:css css/site.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <!-- endbuild -->

  <!-- build:js js/site.js -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src='bower_components/gsap/src/minified/TweenMax.min.js'> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='bower_components/d3/d3.js'> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='bower_components/d3-tip/index.js'> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='bower_components/moment/moment.js'> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='chart.js'> </script>
  <!-- endbuild -->

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

`gulp file`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var usemin = require('gulp-usemin');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');

gulp.task('build', function() {
  return gulp.src(['index.html'])
    .pipe(usemin({
      css: [minifyCss()],
      js: [uglify()]
    }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

After running `gulp build` I am generated a `dist` directory as follows

```
dist/
  css/
    site.css
  index.html
```

And my generated index.html is

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" media="all"/>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there something obvious that I'm missing? Why would the `css` block work but the `js` block silently fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [regex](https://github.com/zont/gulp-usemin/blob/f06f1fb/lib/blocksBuilder.js#L11) used by `gulp-usemin` doesn't allow for any whitespace between the opening `<script>` and closing `</script>` tag. Neither does it allow a `type="text/javascript"` attribute.

See [this regex101 page](https://regex101.com/r/mY7vS7/1) for a matching and non-matching example.

So this:

```
<!-- build:js js/site.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src='bower_components/gsap/src/minified/TweenMax.min.js'> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='bower_components/d3/d3.js'> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='bower_components/d3-tip/index.js'> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='bower_components/moment/moment.js'> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='chart.js'> </script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Should be like this:

```
<!-- build:js js/site.js -->
<script src='bower_components/gsap/src/minified/TweenMax.min.js'></script>
<script src='bower_components/d3/d3.js'></script>
<script src='bower_components/d3-tip/index.js'></script>
<script src='bower_components/moment/moment.js'></script>
<script src='chart.js'></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I'm still encountering the same problem. I've adjusted `index.html` and verified that each of the script tags now matches the given regex. Is there a way to enable warn or error logging?

Comment: I have tried your `build` task on my corrected HTML and it works. So you either haven't adjusted your `index.html` correctly or there's something about your setup that you have failed to mention.

Comment: As for logging just add a `console.log(section[5])` in [this line](https://github.com/zont/gulp-usemin/blob/f06f1fb/lib/blocksBuilder.js#L99). That will tell you if the regex matches.

Comment: In the process of removing each script tag and adding them back one by one, `usemin` has started working again for unknown reasons. Possibly issues with unprintable characters/weird formatting? In any case, thank you for your help.